# VBA (32 bit v 6.5) running speed issue between 32 bit WIN7 and 64 bit Win10 OS

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a a 32 bit excel 2007 vba(6.5) program on a 32 bit windows 7 pro laptop computer with 2.1 GHZ intel cpu. The program uses two Windows APIs which are declared as follows:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long) 
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

The program essentially is running a For loop within a While loop with a 150 ms pause after each loop using the two windows APIs.

The program works perfectly without any problems on the 32 bit laptop. However, when I try to run the program on my Dell laptop with a windows10 pro 64 bit OS and Xeon 4 core, 2,9GHz, 3,8GHz Turbo cpu, A MUCH FASTER laptop, the program starts slower at the begining then speeds up to normal then slows down again at the end.

Does anyone have a clue of what may be causing this issue?
Why am I getting this problem and how can it be fixed. The only cause I can think of, Is it is due to the 32/64 bit difference in OS, or maybe API declarations.

The Sleep API is used to pause 20ms after each While loop, and the GetTickCount API is used to pause 150ms after each For loop.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that is exhibiting this behavior? The `Declare` procedures only lets use know what APIs you're using, but not *how you are using them*.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2010/ff700513(v%3Doffice.11))